# Update build bundle of capacitor js application (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, capacitor

I have a capacitor js app for iOS. It's enterprise app and not exisits in AppStore. Every time when I update the app the users reinstall the app to update it. Is there a way to update the build bundle where are my js and CSS files without update the whole app.

Update: I have a long conversation with Ai. It said that on iOs I have no acces to wbeDir from capacitor config. Is there another strategy to perform updates?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this: https://capgo.app/ or https://ionic.io/appflow.

Both of these will let you do live updates without having to rebuild the native bundle making the users have to reinstall.